# Any way to change a list of radio buttons to a select drop down dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to find a work around to a dynamically created form that for whatever reason doesn't give the option of a select list, only radio and check inputs. There is no way for me to go in and change the code so I was curious if there is a way to transform a list of radio buttons to a select drop down using jquery?

for example, if I have this code:

```
<form>
   <div class="col-lg-5">     
      <p class="bullet"><b><font class="required" size="3" color="FF0000">*     </font></b></p>
      <p class="inputLabel">First Name:</p>
      <input type="text" size="25" name="Text1" value="">
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-5">
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male<br>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-10"><p>Current Employer / Facility:</p>
      <input type="text" size="25" name="Text9" value="">
   </div>
</form>
```

is there anyway to change it to:

```
<form>
    <div class="col-lg-5">     
      <p class="bullet"><b><font class="required" size="3" color="FF0000">*     </font></b></p>
      <p class="inputLabel">First Name:</p>
      <input type="text" size="25" name="Text1" value="">
   </div>
    <select name="gender">
       <option value ="male">Male</option>
       <option value ="female">Female</option>
    </select>
   <div class="col-lg-10"><p>Current Employer / Facility:</p>
      <input type="text" size="25" name="Text9" value="">
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please be clearer: do you own the source code? Do you want this change to be made for everyone or just for you?

Comment: Absolutely. But you haven't posted any code showing what you've tried.

Comment: Not trivial with layout shown. Please show as much html as possible, especially any wrappers for the radios / separators for form controls etc

Comment: The question gets more complicated if there are multiple sets of radio buttons within a form, or multiple forms needing this conversion. It would be helpful to know if either or both is the case.

Comment: I don't know how to approach it, that why I'm asking here. I don't know what other HTML to show, I literally just want to change what I put in the radio buttons to the code I put in the select dropdown

Comment: There's just one very long drop down taking up 90% of the page real estate, no other ones will be affected.

Comment: the issue is getting the text without seeing what comes before/after in the live form or if there is any wrapping element around the radios. If it was acceptable to convert `value` to text would be easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
var sel = $('<select name="gender">').append(function () {
    var opts='';
    $('input[name="gender"]').each(function () {
        opts += '<option value ="' + this.value + '">' + this.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.value.slice(1) + '</option>';
    })
    return opts;
});
$('form div.col-lg-5:eq(1)').empty().append(sel);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ffznueaL/)**

Comment: This works really well thankyou, the only thing is that the radio buttons don't disappear, the drop down is appending the the bottom of the div containing them

Answer (score 0):

```
var select = $("<select></select>").attr("name", "gender");
$('form input[name="gender"]').each(function(index, item) {
    $('<option/>', {
         'value': this.value,
         'text': this.value
    }).appendTo(select);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/un31fw0c/2/) is as close as I was able to get it.

HTML:

```
<form>
   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male<br>
   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
var select = $('form').append($('<select>', {
    name: 'gender',
    id: 'genderSelect'
}));

$("form > input[type='radio']").each(function() {
    $('#genderSelect').append($('<option>', {
        value: $(this).val(),
        text: $(this).val()
    }));
    $(this).remove();
});
```

You'll need to do something with the labels for the radio buttons to grab the values or get rid of them more easily.

Comment: The `>` won't work in the updated question, since the inputs are actually in  a `div` element inside the form. You can just leave it out.

Comment: Ah, right. Thanks for this! I'll leave my code as-is and OP can modify it to the way he wants it.